# Why does this minimal code fail to draw textured triangles with OpenGL ES 1.1?

Tags: ios, memory-management, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

I'm trying to render a 512 * 512 texture onto a 256 * 256 square composed of two triangles.

The goal is to learn how to draw a textured rectangle of two triangles in OpenGL ES 1.1 with the least minimal amount of code possible.

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS:** Problem solved! +500 bounty goes to Sam :-)
At the point where it came to calling glDrawArrays I got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The project uses ARC, created with Xcode 5.0.2 and I tried to run it on both the iPhone 5 simulator as well as an iPhone 5S with the same results. Sam pointed out that instead of enabling a color array with `glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);`, I should enable the texture coordinates array with `glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);`.

I put the second problem in here for completeness if others happen to come here to learn about how to texture polygons in OpenGL ES 1.1.

This is how I setup the CAEAGLLayer:

```
// Configure the drawable properties
CAEAGLLayer *glLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
glLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
    kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

// Create the OpenGL context
EAGLContext *ctx = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
self.context = ctx;
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:ctx];

// Create buffers
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &framebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &renderbuffer);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, renderbuffer);

[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];

glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, renderbuffer);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &framebufferWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &framebufferHeight);


// Config OpenGL ES
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrthof(0, framebufferWidth / self.contentScaleFactor, (framebufferHeight / self.contentScaleFactor), 0, 0, 1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

After the UIView backed by a CAEAGLLayer is created and configured like shown above, I get the pixel data of the UIImage. I added comments with the print output while stepping through:

```
GLubyte *pixelData = (GLubyte*)calloc(_width * _height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte)); // 0x00000001004c8000

CGColorSpaceRef imageCS = CGImageGetColorSpace(img.CGImage); // 0x0000000170027040
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData, _width, _height, 8, _width * 4, imageCS, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); // 0x0000000170161f80

CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, _width, _height), img.CGImage);

CGColorSpaceRelease(imageCS);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

Everything looks fine. The UIImage gets loaded correctly.
Then I use this `pixelData` to create the texture:

```
glGenTextures(1, &_textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (GLsizei)_width, (GLsizei)_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Finally, the CADisplayLink gets created and it calls a `-draw` method which performs the scene drawing operations in a GCD background queue.
This is how I attempt to draw it on screen in the render callback, within the GCD block:

```
CGFloat height = 256;
CGFloat width = 256;

GLshort imageVertices[] = {
    0, height,  // left bottom
    width, height,  // right bottom
    0, 0,       // left top
    width, 0    // right top
};

GLshort textureCoords[] = {
    0, 1,   // left bottom
    1, 1,   // right bottom
    0, 0,   // left top
    1, 0    // right top
};

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureID);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, imageVertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, textureCoords);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

When it reaches glDrawArrays I end up with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Any clue why this might happen? I double checked:

The UIImage used to generate the pixelData does not get deallocated. The UIView backed by CAEAGLLayer does not get deallocated either. The problem also occurs when I remove GCD and render on the main thread.

- The UIImage gets loaded correctly. It is 512 x 512 big.
- The image is a PNG 24 with alpha.
- textureID is set to 1. When I step through it halts nowhere and all values make sense. Until I reach glDrawArrays.

Comment: Where's your `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` call?

Comment: Thank you @genpfault - I updated the question with more code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one may be the problem, you don't actually provide a color array pointer:
`glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);`

`glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);` sets the vertex attribute to a resident value.
Instead of the absent `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`, the texture coord array should be enabled:
`glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);`

The same goes for disabling with `glDisableClientState(...)`:

---

To explicitly target the texture unit 0 and texture coord array 0 respectively, do `glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` before any of the following calls:

- `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`
- `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureID);`
- `glVertexPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, imageVertices);`
- `glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, textureCoords);`

Comment: Thanks Sam! glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY) solved the EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue. The rendered triangles are white however, ignoring the texture. I tried glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); after glGenTextures(1, &tID);.

Comment: You're welcome! `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` is also a per TU state (edited). Difficult to guess, what the remaining problems are. If this doesn't help, exclude blending for now: `glDisable(GL_BLEND);`.

Comment: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); was the problem. I had uncommented it during debugging and forgot to reactivate this line. Now the texture renders! Thank you very much! Do you know why OpenGL would draw a very fine white outline around the objects in the texture that uses alpha transparency?

Comment: Turns out that the outline was in fact part of the image ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to suggest the same :). Should you ever encounter very thin, uniform seams at polygon edges/borders, you can probably improve sampling (interpolation) like this (applied to the texture bound to the current TU):
    `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);` 
    `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);`